# Including image styles in custom module

Tags: 8, media, configuration

I was following [topic](http://www.agoradesign.at/blog/including-image-styles-your-module-or-theme-drupal-8). I can including image style in my custom module. But I have a problem. I can't reinstall module because of following error:

> Unable to install Module ABC, image.style.black_white already exists
>   in active configuration.

Can I include an image style in custom module with file config and maybe reinstall module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is don't delete image style when uninstall module. So when you reinstall image style already exist. Use can use [hook_uninstall](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Extension!module.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/8.2.x) to delete 
image style to finish uninstall: write code in file **module_name.install**

```
<?php
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

function module_name_uninstall() {

  ImageStyle::load('image_style_name')->delete();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to add a new image style 'black_white' but an image style with the same name already exist.

Solution 1. Delete the image style '`black_white`' from `/admin/config/media/image-styles`.

Solution 2. If your module has a image style configuration file "`image.style.black_white.yml`" Check or Remove it.
Have you already installed / uninstalled the module ?

If you have already install/uninstall this module, try to review uninstall processes to clean up properly.